# hive query with join: space available is below the configured reserved amount

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hql

Im executing a sql query with hive on a single node cluster and Im getting this error:

```
 MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-20:  HDFS Read: 4456448 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

In the logs `http://localhost:50070/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-hadoop.log` it appears that space available is below the configured reserved amount:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeResourceChecker: 
Space available on volume '/dev/mapper/vg_hadoop-lv_root' is 40734720,
which is below the configured reserved amount 104857600`
```

Do you understand why this error appears?

Also in the disk analyzer, before execute the query I have 12,6GB free space, and when the execution stops with the error the disk analyzer shows that only 2GB of free space are available. I also update the virtual box machine with more 30GB and the same thing happens.

Full error:

```
    Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[110][bigTable=?] in task 'Stage-20:MAPRED' is a cross product
    Warning: Shuffle Join JOIN[8][tables = [part, supplier]] in Stage 'Stage-1:MAPRED' is a cross product
    Query ID = hadoopadmin_20160324175146_7ab8931d-eeac-4e03-b833-3592ed96521f
    Total jobs = 9
    Stage-27 is selected by condition resolver.
    Stage-1 is filtered out by condition resolver.
    16/03/24 17:51:59 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    Execution log at: /tmp/hadoopadmin/hadoopadmin_20160324175146_7ab8931d-eeac-4e03-b833-3592ed96521f.log
    2016-03-24 17:52:01 Starting to launch local task to process map join;  maximum memory = 518979584
    2016-03-24 17:52:05 Dump the side-table for tag: 1 with group count: 1 into file: file:/tmp/hadoopadmin/614990eb-e755-4bca-bccf-be19bd5c6882/hive_2016-03-24_17-51-46_111_5082675810708688029-1/-local-10017/HashTable-Stage-20/MapJoin-mapfile61--.hashtable
    2016-03-24 17:52:06 Uploaded 1 File to: file:/tmp/hadoopadmin/614990eb-e755-4bca-bccf-be19bd5c6882/hive_2016-03-24_17-51-46_111_5082675810708688029-1/-local-10017/HashTable-Stage-20/MapJoin-mapfile61--.hashtable (938915 bytes)
    2016-03-24 17:52:06 End of local task; Time Taken: 4.412 sec.
    Execution completed successfully
    MapredLocal task succeeded
    Launching Job 2 out of 9
    Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
    Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
    2016-03-24 17:52:10,043 Stage-20 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
    2016-03-24 17:53:10,214 Stage-20 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
    2016-03-24 17:54:10,272 Stage-20 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
    2016-03-24 17:55:10,336 Stage-20 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
    2016-03-24 17:56:10,386 Stage-20 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
    2016-03-24 17:57:10,435 Stage-20 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
    log4j:ERROR Failed to flush writer,
    java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.QuietWriter.flush(QuietWriter.java:59)
        at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:324)
        at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.subAppend(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:369)
        at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
        at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.fatal(Log4JLogger.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Ended Job = job_local60483225_0001 with errors
    Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
    FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
    MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
    Stage-Stage-20:  HDFS Read: 4472832 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
    Total MapR

educe CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
hive>
```

The query:

```
select 
    nation, 
    o_year, 
    sum(amount) as sum_profit 
from
    (select 
        n_name as nation, 
        year(o_orderdate) as o_year, 
        l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount) - ps_supplycost * l_quantity as amount 
    from part, 
        supplier, 
        lineitem, 
        partsupp, 
        orders, 
        nation 
    where
        s_suppkey = l_suppkey and 
        ps_suppkey = l_suppkey and 
        ps_partkey = l_partkey and 
        p_partkey = l_partkey and 
        o_orderkey = l_orderkey and 
        s_nationkey = n_nationkey and 
        p_name like '%plum%' ) as profit 
group by nation, o_year 
order by nation, o_year desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably your issue:

```
Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[110][bigTable=?] in task 'Stage-20:MAPRED' is a cross product
Warning: Shuffle Join JOIN[8][tables = [part, supplier]] in Stage 'Stage-1:MAPRED' is a cross product
```

Cross products tend to turn tables of a few GBs into tables on the order of terabytes if there are many keys... reevaluate your query and ensure it's doing what you think it is.

**Edit** now that you've added the query, I can add more. This portion:

```
from part, 
    supplier, 
    lineitem, 
    partsupp, 
    orders, 
    nation
```

is where you can optimize things. This is creating a cartesian product, which is your issue. What's happening is you're first joining all of the tables in a cross product, and then keeping records based on your `where` clause, rather than joining tables together selectively using an `on` clause. Try out this (admittedly uglier) optimized version of the query:

```
select 
  nation, 
  o_year, 
  sum(amount) as sum_profit
from 
  (select 
    n_name as nation, 
    year(o_orderdate) as o_year, 
    l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount) -  ps_supplycost * l_quantity as amount
   from
      orders o join
      (select 
        l_extendedprice, 
        l_discount, 
        l_quantity, 
        l_orderkey, 
        n_name, 
        ps_supplycost 
       from part p join
         (select 
            l_extendedprice, 
            l_discount, 
            l_quantity, 
            l_partkey, 
            l_orderkey, 
            n_name, 
            ps_supplycost 
          from partsupp ps join
            (select 
                l_suppkey, 
                l_extendedprice, 
                l_discount, 
                l_quantity, 
                l_partkey, 
                l_orderkey, 
                n_name 
             from
               (select s_suppkey, n_name 
                from nation n join supplier s on n.n_nationkey = s.s_nationkey
               ) s1 join lineitem l on s1.s_suppkey = l.l_suppkey
            ) l1 on ps.ps_suppkey = l1.l_suppkey and ps.ps_partkey = l1.l_partkey
         ) l2 on p.p_name like '%plum%' and p.p_partkey = l2.l_partkey
     ) l3 on o.o_orderkey = l3.l_orderkey
  )profit
group by nation, o_year
order by nation, o_year desc;
```

Per this [benchmarking script](https://github.com/JerryLead/BenchmarkScripts/blob/master/tpch/hive/queries/q9_product_type_profit.hive).

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the query seems ok. Im using a standard query for hive with tpc benchmark.